# Swift Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred

Tags: swift, generics, data-structures, xcode11

I have a generic dictionary, and built a generic function to access that dictionary (to prevent concurrency access problems).

My (singleton) data class looks like:

```
class AppData {
    static let genericDict: Dictionary<String, Any> = [:]
    
    static func genericGet<T: Any>(_ objID: String) -> T {
        let retVal: T
        mySemaphore.wait()
        retVal = genericDict[objID] as! T
        mySemaphore.signal()
        return retVal
    }
}
```

However, when I call my function like so:

```
class SomeClass {
     let product: SomeObj = AppData.genericGet(objID) as! SomeObj
}
```

I get the error:
`Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred`

I both explicitly and implicitly cast the type to my desired value. Not sure what else I can do to fix this issue.

I've tried restarting XCode, does not help.

The real code:

```
public class AppData: ObservableObject {
    static private var dataDirectory: Dictionary<String, Any> = Dictionary(minimumCapacity: 10000)
    
    static let dataGetLock = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)
    static func get<T: Any>(_ objID: String) -> T? {
        let retVal: T
        dataGetLock.wait()
        retVal = dataDirectory[objID] as! T
        dataGetLock.signal()
        return retVal
    }
}
```

I get the error on the following two lines:

```
class StoreViewEnvironment: ObservableObject {
    func initProductLoad(storeID: String) {
    ...
        let liveStore: Store = AppData.get(storeID) as! Store
        let liveMenu: Menu = AppData.get(liveStore.menuID) as! Menu
    ... 
   }
}
```

Comment: Is that your real code? If so, it makes no sense; you are saying `AppData.genericGet` but `genericGet` is not a static func. Similarly, you are calling `genericDict`, which is a static constant, from within `genericGet` which is not a static func. All of that is impossible. Please copy and paste _real code_ into the question; do not attempt to type or make up code in a question. — Also, what is `mySemaphore`? Do not show code that depends on code you have not shown.

Comment: Obviously that was a typo and clearly this is not real code. I can post my real code below but my concern was that the auxiliary data structures would make the actual problem more opaque. I'll add the real code below.

Comment: `mySemaphore` is a generic semaphore in case that somehow added complexity I was unaware of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't approve of the way you're doing this (on the general grounds that Any is just about always a bad smell), but here's a version that compiles (just delete the `Any` constraint):

```
class AppData {
    static let genericDict: Dictionary<String, Any> = [:]
    
    static func get<T>(_ objID: String) -> T {
        let retVal: T
        retVal = genericDict[objID] as! T
        return retVal
    }
}

class SomeClass {
    let product : String = AppData.get("yoho")
}
```

Comment: Appreciate your answer – however this fix would undermine much of the reason to use generics in the first place. I use a `Dictionary<String, Any>` to store data - regardless of type - in one place. Additionally as I said in the question, AppData is a singleton (you couldn't create it differently for different types). Originally, I just called the dictionary directly. However, this yielded thread concurrency problems. Hence the explicit get function.

Comment: OK I see, I'll completely change my answer. :)

Comment: OK, done editing. Basically the Any generic constraint was wrong.

Comment: The implementation of `ofType: T.Type` fixed the problem. Not sure where that went from the answer. This seems like a nuanced fix, why did that work? What was wrong with my code?

Comment: You can do it either way. But in any case the `:Any` needs to go. In the code I have now, the `product : String` declaration disambiguates the type; if you want to pass the type instead that's fine too. :)